# Storing the data at the end of the For loop

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I have a For loop

```
Files = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}},
   {{11, 12}, {13, 14}, {15, 16}, {17, 18}},
   {{21, 22}, {23, 24}, {25, 26}, {27, 28}},
   {{31, 32}, {33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}},
   {{41, 42}, {43, 44}, {45, 46}, {47, 48}}};
lnth = Length[Files];
For[tp = 1, tp < lnth + 1, tp++,
 sd = Files[[tp]];
 sdd = {#1, #2^2} & @@@ sd;
 ]
```

For each value of *tp*, the result must be stored as a new column in a data file. Eventually, the resultant file has to be like

```
{{1,4,11,144,21,484,31,1024,41,1764},{3,16,13,196,23,576,33,1156,43,1936},{5,36,15,256,25,676,35,1296,45,2116},{7,64,17,324,27,784,37,1444,47,2304}}
```

Please help to improve the code to have the resultant file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Files = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{11, 12}, {13, 14}, {15, 16}, {17,
      18}}, {{21, 22}, {23, 24}, {25, 26}, {27, 28}}, {{31, 32}, {33, 
     34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}}, {{41, 42}, {43, 44}, {45, 46}, {47, 48}}};

lnth = Length[Files]; sdd = {};
For[tp = 1, tp < lnth + 1, tp++, sd = Files[[tp]];
 AppendTo[sdd, {#1, #2^2} & @@@ sd];]

res = Flatten /@ Transpose@sdd

(* {{1, 4, 11, 144, 21, 484, 31, 1024, 41, 1764}, {3, 16, 13, 196, 23, 576, 33, 
  1156, 43, 1936}, {5, 36, 15, 256, 25, 676, 35, 1296, 45, 2116}, {7, 64, 17, 
  324, 27, 784, 37, 1444, 47, 2304}} *)
```

Alternatively,

```
res = Flatten /@ Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]^2} &, Transpose@Files, {2}]

(* {{1, 4, 11, 144, 21, 484, 31, 1024, 41, 1764}, {3, 16, 13, 196, 23, 576, 33, 
  1156, 43, 1936}, {5, 36, 15, 256, 25, 676, 35, 1296, 45, 2116}, {7, 64, 17, 
  324, 27, 784, 37, 1444, 47, 2304}} *)
```

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon, Thanks for your help

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon , I apply  res = Flatten /@ Transpose@sdd; to a larger data set. sometimes it doesnt work on similar data sets. I see following errors : Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{{9.9940898437500000,1.19916},<<49>>,<<1690>>},<<8>>} cannot be transposed.   and   Transpose::tperm: Permutation {9.9940898437500000,1.19916,9.9715968750000000,<<46>>,1.19776,<<31270>>} is longer than the dimensions {18} of the expression........ I want to have this with For loop. Can you please give your feedback?

Answer (score 6):

When `Map` and `Transpose` appear together, think about `MapThread` :)

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}},
   {{11, 12}, {13, 14}, {15, 16}, {17, 18}},
   {{21, 22}, {23, 24}, {25, 26}, {27, 28}},
   {{31, 32}, {33, 34}, {35, 36}, {37, 38}},
   {{41, 42}, {43, 44}, {45, 46}, {47, 48}}} /.{x_,y_}->{x,y^2}//
MapThread[Join]
```

Comment: @ AsukaMinato, thank you